# Instantiating object in a function gives "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Tags: javascript, undefined, hoisting

I tried to look most of the suggested search results concerning the error message I receive, but unfortunately none is talking about a case that is similar to mine. So I believe this is not a duplicate.

*(In particular I don't use jQuery, I don't want to use it. Besides, the accepted answer given is correct and it does not involve jQuery, it elaborates the understanding of hoisting in JavaScript.)*

I wonder **Why the code below (2nd code snippet) does not work?** I can't figure that out.

---

### This code works. I instantiate Cell objects outside the drawGrid function.

```js
 'use strict';

 var dim = 20;
 var side_length = 25;

 var canvas = document.getElementById('world');
 canvas.width = 500;
 canvas.height = 500;
 document.body.appendChild(canvas);

 if (canvas.getContext) {
   var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
   drawGrid(ctx);
 }

 var Cell = function(x, y, alive, context) {
   this.x = x;
   this.y = y;
   this.alive = alive;
   this.ctx = context;
 };

 Cell.prototype.draw = function() {
   if (this.alive === true) {
     this.ctx.beginPath();
     this.ctx.arc(this.x + side_length / 2, this.y + side_length / 2, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
     this.ctx.fill();
   }
 };

 for (var i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
   for (var j = 0; j < dim; j++) {
     var x = i * canvas.width / dim,
       y = j * canvas.height / dim;
     new Cell(x, y, true, ctx).draw();
   }
 }

 function drawGrid(ctx) {
   for (var i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
     for (var j = 0; j < dim; j++) {
       var x = i * canvas.width / dim,
         y = j * canvas.height / dim;
       ctx.strokeRect(x, y, side_length, side_length);
     }
   }
 }
```

```html
<canvas id='world'></canvas>
```

---

### This code does not work. I instantiate the Cell objects inside the drawGrid function.

```js
 'use strict';

 var dim = 20;
 var side_length = 25;

 var canvas = document.getElementById('world');
 canvas.width = 500;
 canvas.height = 500;
 document.body.appendChild(canvas);

 if (canvas.getContext) {
   var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
   drawGrid(ctx);
 }

 var Cell = function(x, y, alive, context) {
   this.x = x;
   this.y = y;
   this.alive = alive;
   this.ctx = context;
 };

 Cell.prototype.draw = function() {
   if (this.alive === true) {
     this.ctx.beginPath();
     this.ctx.arc(this.x + side_length / 2, this.y + side_length / 2, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
     this.ctx.fill();
   }
 };


 function drawGrid(ctx) {
   for (var i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
     for (var j = 0; j < dim; j++) {
       var x = i * canvas.width / dim,
         y = j * canvas.height / dim;
       ctx.strokeRect(x, y, side_length, side_length);
       new Cell(x, y, true, ctx).draw();
     }
   }
 }
```

```html
<canvas id='world'></canvas>
```

Comment: On which line is the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
 if (canvas.getContext) {
   var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
   drawGrid(ctx);
 }

 var Cell = function(x, y, alive, context) {
```

You're assigning `Cell` **after** you call `drawGrid`. So, inside `drawGrid`, `Cell` is `undefined`.

Simple fix 1, use a standard function declaration to have the assignment [hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) along the variable declaration :

```
 function Cell(x, y, alive, context) {
```

Simple (more readable) fix 2:  just move the call to `drawGrid` at the end.

Comment: Correct. Would also be a good idea to tell the OP about Hositing in JS. (aka, why does your fix actually solves his problem)

Comment: Thank you guys. Will google Hositing in JS then. Or would it be possible to explain it to me as if I was a 8 year old? Thanks again.

Comment: Perfect. You got my vote (in 10h) and acceptance (in 5 minutes). Much appreciated.